Fantasy manga in which the red-haired female lead was a swordswoman and demigod who regressed to the past after dying to her ex-lover
The female lead was a red-haired girl and swordsman who had regressed to the past after dying to her ex-lover, who became the king of a country named Bahumut or something. She swore that she would become his sword in her next life. During the manga, it was revealed that her mother was a god and the last god, and she killed her as her mother realised what she had done and asked for death.

Hi there, welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you read this manga?

Is this Adonis...?

Ianna and Arhad had much in common. They both only cared about themselves, and were madly obsessed with each other. The difference is one wanted the other's warmth, and the other wanted submission. Though Ianna's life ended in a heated battle against Arhad, the Kingdom's emperor, she is reincarnated into the same life for reasons unknown. Two people who faced misery in their previous life now have a chance to meet again. Will the same tragedy repeat itself, or can Ianna change the course of history?

The red-haired female lead is Ianna Roberstein, the half-noble daughter of Count Cherno Roberstein from the Kingdom of Roan. The male lead is Arhad Bahamut, a prince and later the Emperor of the neighbouring Bahamut Empire.
In the first chapter, Ianna and Arhad are duelling with swords on a flaming battlefield. Ianna loses and dies from her wounds. Just before she dies, she promises that rather than being his enemy, she'll become his knight in her next life. She then regresses back to her childhood.



In chapter 14, Ianna learns that her mother, Count Roberstein's second wife, Lebony, was secretly the last of a race of gods who once walked the Earth before humans. Lebony had always treated Ianna cruelly, resenting her for inheriting her divine power. Regretting her past actions, Lebony asked Ianna to take her life and Ianna obliged, impaling her with her sword.



You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.
